# Unexpected Result Updating a Copy of a DF when using iterrows

Tags: pandas, loops

When I ran this code, I was expected df2 to update accurately but it does not. Here is the code...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
exam_data = [{'name':'Anastasia', 'score':12.5}, {'name':'Dima','score':9}, {'name':'Katherine','score':16.5}]
df = pd.DataFrame(exam_data)
df2 = df.copy()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df2['score'] = row['score'] * 2
    print(row['name'], row['score'])

print(df2)
```

As you can see from the output below, the scores did not double, they were all set to 33.0

```
Anastasia 12.5
Dima 9.0
Katherine 16.5
        name  score
0  Anastasia   33.0
1       Dima   33.0
2  Katherine   33.0
```

What is going on, why am I seeing that unanticipated result?

Comment: You can use `df2.update(df.score.mul(2))` rather than for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Because you set `df2['score']` every time you iteration. Try to make a change:

```
row['score'] = row['score'] * 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas works column-wise; instead of iterating over the rows (which is slow), you can just use

```
df2['score'] = df['score'] * 2
```

That will update the entire column at once.